# using angular 2 cli after starting the project without it.

Tags: angular, web, webclient, angular-cli

I've Started a project with Angular 2 and built some modules and components without angular-cli. Now I want to continue the project from this point with cli, is there any way to adjust the old features to the cli or should I start everything from scratch?

Comment: Just move your files to angular-cli project. What is the problem?

Comment: I would suggest creating a new angular-cli project, copy over your components, and if you have any external modules loaded, then re-run your npm commands to install them. should be as easy as that.

Comment: After I did that I had to configure that npm start will also boot the ng-serve, otherwise the project wasn't uploading. except that I can understand from you guys that it is safe.

Comment: create a new angular cli app, copy all your angular components, modules, pipes ...etc. You'll have to do some tweaks to make sure all your imports are correct and so on.